# Reading and writing in binary file using iteration on C++

Tags: c++, file, binary

I'm doing a schoolwork involving a system that saves structs on a binary file, with that being necessary(?) the use of iteration.

I'm having problem both with writing (not sure if it is right):

```
void InserirDados () {

    //var created to acknowledge the quantity of items that will be described
    int quantidade;

    cout << "Quantos personagens voce pretende inserir nesta sessao?" << endl;
    cin >> quantidade;

    //allocating memory like it's asked by the teacher
    PersonagemDesenho* objPersonagem = new PersonagemDesenho[quantidade];

    //declaring the flow of data
    ofstream arquivo ("personagens.dat", ios::binary);

    //flush buffer
    cin.ignore ();

    cout << "(A utilizacao de espacos e' permitida para todos os itens a seguir)" << endl;

    //describing items
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
        cout << " - PERSONAGEM NUMERO: " << i + 1 << endl;

        cout << "Digite o nome do personagem a ser inserido" << endl;
        //getline for getting more than 1 word
        getline(cin, objPersonagem[i].nomePersonagem);

        cout << "Digite o nome do criador do personagem" << endl;
        getline(cin, objPersonagem[i].nomeCriador);

        //writing code
        arquivo.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*> (&objPersonagem[i]), sizeof(PersonagemDesenho));
        }
    cout << "As informacoes serao salvas no arquivo \"personagens.dat\"" << endl;
    //closing file
    arquivo.close();
}
```

and reading data:

```
void ListaDados () {

    ifstream arquivo ("personagens.dat", ios::binary);
    int i = 0;

    while (???) {
        arquivo.read(reinterpret_cast<const char*> (&objPersonagens[i]) sizeof(PersonagemDesenho))
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted simpler things first? Can write and read *one* `PersonagemDesenho`? Can you read and write one `int`?

Comment: I've already done a lot of text files exercises, but this is my first shot at binaries, because we don't have any exercises about them.

Comment: Does your textbook say anything about binary files? Did you consider a Google search for "C++ write binary file"?

Comment: Serializing seems too complicated for a schoolwork of a course from the first period of my university's program. I can say with 99% of confidence that the teachers are not asking this.

Comment: Of course I did research, I've been at this today for something around 9-10 hours straight. Without research, I couldn't have written this code. The best I found for this particular problem was this link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214789/armazenamento-em-arquivo-bin%C3%A1rio

But it uses terms which never I've never seen and the teachers never spoke of.

Comment: When you attempt something new, it is best to start with a small, simple version, then build up by small steps. (For some reason, schools never teach this.) In the 9 hours you worked on this, did you succeed at writing/reading one `int`? That really is the fastest way to arrive at code that writes/reads multiple `PersonagemDesenhos`.

Comment: To tell you truth, @Beta, the thought of trying it didn't even came to my mind until suggested it and I'll surely try this out tomorrow. Thanks for caring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear from your use of `std::getline()` that `nomePersonagem` and `nomeCriador` are `std::string` values. `std::string` is a dynamic type (it holds a pointer to data stored elsewhere in memory). You can't write/read a struct as-is when it contains dynamic data in it. You would write/read the pointer itself, not the data being pointed at.

The solution to this problem requires *serializing* the data into a flatter format when writing, and *deserializing* the data when reading.

Try something more like this instead:

```
void writeSizeT(ostream &out, size_t value) {
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
}

void writeString(ostream &out, const string &value) {
    size_t len = value.size();
    writeSizeT(out, len);
    out.write(s.c_str(), len);
}

void InserirDados () {
    //var created to acknowledge the quantity of items that will be described
    int quantidade;

    cout << "Quantos personagens voce pretende inserir nesta sessao?" << endl;
    cin >> quantidade;

    //allocating memory like it's asked by the teacher
    PersonagemDesenho* objPersonagem = new PersonagemDesenho[quantidade];

    //declaring the flow of data
    ofstream arquivo ("personagens.dat", ios::binary);

    writeSizeT(arquivo, quantidade);

    //flush buffer
    cin.ignore ();

    cout << "(A utilizacao de espacos e' permitida para todos os itens a seguir)" << endl;

    //describing items
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
        cout << " - PERSONAGEM NUMERO: " << i + 1 << endl;

        //getline for getting more than 1 word
        cout << "Digite o nome do personagem a ser inserido" << endl;
        getline(cin, objPersonagem[i].nomePersonagem);
        cout << "Digite o nome do criador do personagem" << endl;
        getline(cin, objPersonagem[i].nomeCriador);

        //writing code
        writeString(arquivo, objPersonagem[i].nomePersonagem);
        writeString(arquivo, objPersonagem[i].nomeCriador);
    }

    cout << "As informacoes serao salvas no arquivo \"personagens.dat\"" << endl;

    //closing file
    arquivo.close();

    // freeing memory
    delete[] objPersonagem;
}
```

```
size_t readSizeT(istream &in) {
    size_t value;
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
    return value;
}

string readString(istream &in) {
    string value;
    size_t len = readSizeT(in);
    if (len > 0) {
        value.resize(len);  
        in.read(&s[0], len);
    }
    return value;
}

void ListaDados () {
    ifstream arquivo ("personagens.dat", ios::binary);

    size_t quantidade = readSizeT(arquivo);

    //allocating memory like it's asked by the teacher
    PersonagemDesenho* objPersonagem = new PersonagemDesenho[quantidade];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < quantidade; ++i) {
        //reading code
        objPersonagem[i].nomePersonagem = readString(arquivo);
        objPersonagem[i].nomeCriador = readString(arquivo);
    }

    // freeing memory
    delete[] objPersonagem;

    //closing file
    arquivo.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Is there something that you recommend me so I can fully understand what you did? Like a book or something like that.